Words that describe a person, in usage, used to describe, also, other, unrelated, characteristics of that same person
I have observed the following pattern in Spanish language usage (and, perhaps, also in other languages).
The pattern is:
Words that describe a person (and, in particular, a specific, characteristic, of that person), in usage, are used to describe/refer to, also, other, unrelated, characteristics of that same person.
I wonder whether, technically, there is a name for this phenomenon/usage.
Thanks.

Ey, Joselin, welcome to the site. Could you please edit your question adding some examples of that phenomenon? For me it's not clear exactly what you mean.

El fenómeno que describes podría estar relacionado con la metonimia (metonymy en inglés). La metonimia es una figura retórica en la que una cosa o concepto se designa con el nombre de algo estrechamente relacionado con esa cosa o concepto. En el contexto que mencionas, una palabra que describe una característica específica de una persona puede utilizarse para referirse a otras características o aspectos de esa persona debido a su asociación.
Por ejemplo, llamar a alguien «cerebro» para referirse a su inteligencia, y luego utilizar «cerebro» para referirse a sus decisiones o acciones, aunque esas acciones no estén relacionadas con la inteligencia.
https://www.significados.com/metonimia/
